# Weed eater dies when idling or not at full throttle, but is near catching fire at full throttle

Tags: small-engine

As the title says, my weed eater dies unless I run it wide open. If I release the throttle, it will die flat out without hesitation. Running it wide open causes it get red hot. It melted part of the inside of the plastic engine cover during my last use, which lead to fear of it catching fire. The weed eater starts usually on the second or third pull, with the throttle wide open.

I know a little about small engine repair and have an idea that the issue is coming from the carburetor, but I also noticed the exhaust manifold (not sure if this is the correct part name) has a broken weld where the mounting screws go. This weld explains the amount of smoke that I noticed and the thick black oil buildup where it shouldn't be.

I also suspect that the fuel/ oil mixture ratio is not correct based on the oil build-up.

Am I correct to assume the carburetor would case the idle dying... possibly clogged?

---

Weed Eater Brand: BlumenGarten

- I cannot find a website or company associated with the brand. Therefore I am unable to find replacement parts or a manual.
- As of right now, I have mostly done a visual inspection. Given that I am not a small engine mechanic, I have hesitated on removing too many parts to do a deeper inspection.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? You haven't told us about anything you've done so far to diagnose. 2-strokes need exhaust backpressure to function, so an exhaust leak will affect performance. Fuel/oil mix is important. A clean carburetor is, of course, important. Most 2-strokes have a fuel/air mix adjustment, and an idle speed adjustment. Do some research on your make and model. This sounds like a fuel/air issue to me, like maybe a cracked component is allowing the engine to suck in air (and except for at full throttle your fuel/air mix is bad). Check all hoses and fuel-related components.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot find anything about my weed eater. I live in Italy and we are subject to brands that are here one day and gone the next. The brand is BlumenGarten, but when I search for it the only that shows up is a music band.

Comment: I would strip it down (but perhaps not completely disassemble the carb) and look for obvious problems. This is also your chance to find your carb adjustment screws, empty and discard all old fuel, clean all components. Take pictures along the way if there is any chance of confusion when reassembling...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: 2-stroke engines using a diaphragm type carburetor uses crankcase pressure/vacuum to operate the diaphragm, pulling the fuel/oil mix from the tank (vacuum phase) then pumping fuel into the carb jet as vacuum pulls the fuel/oil/air mixture into the cylinder. The diaphragm should have one or more movable flaps serving as valves; vacuum retracting the flexible membrane, pressure closing it. If your carb is a little rectangular object, you should be able to find plenty of online operating principles of these carbs, drawings, photo illustrations, etc. They're all similar in basic operation.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're not getting enough fuel. When you run it wide open, it still isn't getting enough fuel so it is running in a lean state, which creates a LOT of heat, and thus your near-thermonuclear meltdown. You'll need to either clean the carb or get it replaced to make it work right. If you have a sonic cleaner, you can take the carb off of the weedeater and clean it fairly much assembled. It is the easiest way to get into the small orifices to get them clean without completely taking it apart.